# C# transforming object to dynamic object based on json config

Tags: c#, automapper

I will receive an object and need to transform it to different (dynamic) object based on json config.

example:

```
public class Foo
{
    public int Bar { get; set; }
    public string Baz { get; set; }
}

var inputObj = new Foo() { Bar = 1, Baz = "Tom" };
```

expected output object

```
outputObj = {Count = 1, Name = "Tom"}
```

The output object will be construct based on some json config like this:

```
{
  "Foo": {
    "Bar": {
      "MapTo": "Count"
    },
    "Baz": {
      "MapTo": "Name"
    }
  }
}
```

Json config can be change after some time. Can I use automapper for that mapping?  Is there easy way for applay this json config as a mapper config?

Comment: Hello Dear, Did you get any workaround for this question?

Comment: Hey hey, unfortunately I didn't found solution that would me happy, but you can create dynamic mapper for this, and easiest way for doing it will be by using external library for example: [DynamicExpresso](https://github.com/dynamicexpresso/DynamicExpresso)

Comment: Did you try using C#  ExpandoObject with dynamic class ?